# Unable to identify value of input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have watched many tutorials on how to solve this problem and even trying to log it into the console. However since I am quite new to this part of coding I feel like I have made a mistake, could someone please identify so I understand?

I tried using the <.value> but it didn't seem to exist on VScode which was very odd.

here is my code:

```js
const email = document.getElementById('emailId');
const password = document.getElementById('passwordId');
const repassword = document.getElementById('passwordreconfirmId'); 

let evalue = email.setAttribute(value,);
let pvalue = password.setAttribute(value,);
let rpvalue = repassword.setAttribute(value,);

function popup() {
    if (evalue, pvalue, rpvalue === 4) {
        document.getElementById('nextButton').removeAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('nextButton').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="Password-Text">
    <input type="password" onload="passwordvalue" class="pswd" id="passwordId">
</div>

<div class="Password-Text-Reconfirm">
    <input type="password" onload="repasswordvalue" class="re-pswd" id="passwordreconfirmId">
</div>

<div class="next_page"> 
    <button disabled="disabled" onload="popup()" type="submit" id="nextButton">
        <style>
        </style>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I tried using the `<.value>`"_ - unclear what you mean by that.

Comment: `let evalue = email.setAttribute(value,);` is a syntax error (there's a comma followed by nothing). Plus, the variable `value` doesn't exist. And this method returns nothing, why are you getting its return value in a variable? Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) ? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Input elements and buttons do not fire `load` events, btw. (Unless they were `<input type="image">` perhaps.)

Comment: *"I feel like I have made a mistake"* - More than one, I'm afraid.  Quite a few.  Now is a good time to start looking at your browser's developer console, on which you'll observe an error message.  You'll likely want to scrap whatever you're attempting here and return to some introductory tutorials on JavaScript, starting with some smaller attempts and getting used to the basics.

Comment: I updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77873274/295783) since I realised you likely did not want to test if password was equal to "4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to test each value and use && (and) here `evalue, pvalue, rpvalue === 4`. ***NOTE***, a field value is a string, so "4", not 4
2. You cannot get a value using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) since it returns undefined. We could use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and that would work better;  You would need quotes to get the attribute: `password.getAttribute('value')` for example but you can just use password.[value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#value)
3. No need to remove or setAttribute for disabled, just set the atribute to the boolean result of the test. Use a ! (not) if the test gives a positive result that means enable the element like this:

   ```
   let passwordsEqual = (pvalue !=="" && pvalue === rpvalue); // are the the same and not empty
   document.getElementById('nextButton').disabled = !passwordsEqual; // NOT passwordsEqual will disable
   // OR 
   let passwordsNotEqual = (pvalue !=="" && pvalue !== rpvalue); // are the the different and not empty
   document.getElementById('nextButton').disabled = passwordsNotEqual;
   ```
4. There are no onload on elements. Only on frames, iframes and images

Here is a working version - I assumed you wanted to test if the password and the confirmPasswords are the same

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when the page is loaded
  const password = document.getElementById('passwordId');
  const repassword = document.getElementById('passwordreconfirmId');

  function checkPassword() {
    let pvalue = password.value.trim();
    let rpvalue = repassword.value.trim();
    let passwordsEqual = (pvalue && pvalue === rpvalue);        // are the the same and not empty
    document.getElementById('nextButton').disabled = !passwordsEqual; // NOT passwordsEqual will disable
  }
  password.addEventListener('input', checkPassword); // assign the function to the two fields
  repassword.addEventListener('input', checkPassword);

});
```

```html
<div class="Password-Text">
  <input type="password" class="pswd" id="passwordId">
</div>

<div class="Password-Text-Reconfirm">
  <input type="password" class="re-pswd" id="passwordreconfirmId">
</div>

<div class="next_page">
  <button disabled="disabled" type="submit" id="nextButton">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
const password = document.getElementById('passwordId');
const repassword = document.getElementById('passwordreconfirmId'); 

function handleChange() {
    if (password.value === repassword.value) {
        document.getElementById('nextButton').removeAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('nextButton').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="Password-Text">
    <input type="password" oninput="handleChange()" class="pswd" id="passwordId">
</div>

<div class="Password-Text-Reconfirm">
    <input type="password" oninput="handleChange()" class="re-pswd" id="passwordreconfirmId">
</div>

<div class="next_page"> 
    <button disabled="disabled" type="submit" id="nextButton">
      Next Button
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I wish I could give yours a tick because both your posts helped me find an adequate solution, so thank you for your answer.